# What does it mean for Force vector $F(3 , -4)$ to act at point $A(2 , 3)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

***Problem :***

> Graph Force vector $F(3 , -4)$ acting at point $A(2 , 3)$ Where $O$ is the Origin  Point.

***My Attempt :***

> i graphed both force vector ($F$) and Point $A$ but Force Vector ($F$) does not seem to be acting at Point $A$ by any means , because Force Vector to me seems to be acting at the Orgin Point.
>   [image]

that's it thanks in advance.

Comment: the vector starts at the point and points in the direction defined. (at least that is what I was taught in my physics class)

Comment: @Bor Kari so in my case the vector should be vector (AF)  not vector (OA)  ... if i understood you correctly

Comment: yes, just move the vector from the origin and place it at the desired point. That is how vector fields work. Given a point, they give you the direction and magnitude from that point

Comment: @Bor Kari so basically point A is just the starting point of the vector ?

Comment: Yes. I added a picture to make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picture:
[image]

Your vector starts at A as if A was your origin. Note that given a vector field such as $F=(x,2y)$ and point $(1,1)$, the vector starts st that point and points in the direction $(1,2)$.

Comment: great , thanks alot.

Comment: i had one last question , what should be the norm of vector AF ? is it $\sqrt{(3-2) + (-4-3)}$ or it should be equal to the norm of original vector OF
$\sqrt{(3)^2 + (-4)^2}$

Comment: it should be equal to the original vector. Which is $(3^2+(-4^2))^{0.5}$. Or $((5-2)^2+(-1-3)^2))^{0.5}$. For the second one I just found where the tip of the vector was and found the length.